# Is it possible to add column name from the other's column value

Tags: sql, pivot

Given table:

```
ID   NAME  VALUE 

1     A     N

1     B     Y   

1     C     N
```

I want the table in below format:

```
ID  A   B   C

1   N   Y   N
```

Comment: search for "SQL pivot", both on this site and elsewhere.  There are many options, some DBMS-specific.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh RDBMS only

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional aggregation

```
select id, 
       max(case when name='A' then value end) as A,
       max(case when name='B' then value end) as B,
       max(case when name='C' then value end) as C
from tablename
group by id
```

Comment: Note that this is a product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified.

Comment: @jarlh, does conditional aggregation product specific? as far i know, it should work regardless of any product

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals, use double quotes for delimited identifiers, i.e. `as "A"`. (But I'd rather skip it, and simply do `as A`.)

Comment: what if we have thousands of line, we can't use case for thousands value. Is there any other solution ?

Comment: @SHUBHAMKUMAR . . . There is no problem with thousands of *rows* in the table.  If you have thousands of *columns* in your desired result set, then many databases will not even support tables or result sets with so many columns.